# VS Code Pylance - Import ".XXX" could not be resolved

Tags: python

The below screenshot shows the contents of an `__init__.py` file which Pylance thinks has some missing imports.

Why are some of the imports resolvable and some are not?

The directory containing this `__init__.py` file contains the files listed in the import statements:

- `parameter_base.py`
- `parameter_boolean.py`
- `parameter_search_type.py`
- `parameter_tristate.py`
- etc...

The directory structure looks like this:

```
src/
  liburl/
    __init__.py
    url_builder.py
    url_parameter_types/
      __init__.py
      parameter_base.py
      parameter_boolean.py
      parameter_search_type.py
      etc...
```

What I find confusing is that `ParameterBoolean` imports ok.

```
# parameter_boolean.py

from .parameter_base import ParameterBase

class ParameterBoolean():

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.state = None

    def set_state(self, state) -> None:
        if not isinstance(state, bool):
            raise ValueError('state must be of type bool')

        self.state = state

    def get_state(self) -> bool:
        return self.state
```

whereas `ParameterSearchType` does not.

```
# parameter_search_type.py

from enum import Enum

from .parameter_base import ParameterBase

class SearchTypeEnum(Enum):
    FOR_SALE = 1

class ParameterSearchType(ParameterBase):

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self.state = SearchTypeEnum.FOR_SALE

    def get_state(self) -> SearchTypeEnum:
        return self.state
```

There doesn't seem to be much difference between these files and Pylance shows no obvious problems.

[image: pylance]

Comment: Pylance is just a warning message.  If you run the code, do you also get errors?

Answer (score 0):

CTRL+SHIFT+P

```
Python: Restart Language Server
```